# Query for games where the difference of player ratings was big

Tags: software, database, programming

I want  to run a query on a chess games collection which would give me games played by strong players vs weak players, let's say games from the first round of Open tournaments (Swiss system) where grandmasters face amateurs, so basically a query for games where rating difference is bigger than x.

What tools would you suggest? what method?

Comment: Chessbase MegaDatabase? Add rating as filter?

Comment: @Student T have you tried to run such a query? can you demonstrate how?  from that what I have I don't think it is not possible to build the query in I mean in this tool.  ELO filter under CTRL F window  gives only those 4 options  Elo range  for one/none/both/average.

Comment: What is the games collection format? PGN?

Comment: A primitive "solution" would be to use chessbase mega database, add rating floor of 2500 for one player, and then sort the results according to rating for one of the players. The games highest/lowest, depending on sorting order, will have big rating differences. However, I'm not sure that this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Scounged that would do the trick

Comment: The solution proposed by Scounged does the trick somehow however it returns many unwanted results like "one player above 2500 + second player with a rating close to the first player" or "both above 2500". Does anybody have a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to a Chess Query Language tool you can use that, albeit I'm not familiar with it. SCID is free and more easily available : http://scid.sourceforge.net/

1)Open your pgn file

2)Search header rating differences white - black = 200 - 40000